# Raggedright and caption package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I am trying to format my tables and figures' captions with the `caption` package. What I want is the caption label separated from the caption text by a new line and both of them completly to the left margin. Here is my attempt (and MWE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
   labelsep=newline,
   justification=raggedright,
   labelfont=bf
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[htpb]\centering
\caption{Title.}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}\toprule
  abc & abc & abc \\
  abc & abc & abc \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image: Caption with options enabled]

This only way to do what I want is to created a long title:

[image: Long title with option disabled]

Then the `raggedleft` option works:

[image: Long title with raggedleft]

Am I missing something ? Why don't `raggedright` and `raggedleft` options work for a sort caption ?

Comment: Add the option `singlelinecheck=off` to deactivate centered short captions.

Comment: If you have an up-to-date TeX distribution, loading `xunicode` and `xltxtra` is not recommended any more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, short captions (spanning no more than one line) will be centered (this is so in standard LaTeX, and the `caption` package honors this convention); deactivate this using `singlelinecheck=off`:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
   labelsep=newline,
   justification=raggedright,
   labelfont=bf,
  singlelinecheck=off
}
```