# Multiline Caption

Tags: captions

I want a caption of two lines, with the second line not centered but aligned to the left.

[image]

This is the result of the following code, `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}` doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \toprule
  A & B 
\\ \midrule
  11111111111111111  & 1111111111111111\\
  22222222222222222  & 2222222222222222\\
  33333333333333333  & 3333333333333333\\
  44444444444444444  & 4444444444444444\\
  55555555555555555  & 5555555555555555\\
  66666666666666666  & 6666666666666666\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption caption caption caption\\
caption caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try  \captionsetup{width=0.5\linewidth,justification=raggedright}

Comment: Would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128485/34618

Comment: Interestingly it also seems to depend on the length of the caption. If I add two extra `caption` after the `\\` then it is left aligned, but only one, and the last line is centered.

Comment: The trick from this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120411/raggedright-and-caption-package, seems to help. No idea though why this check interfere

Comment: or you could just use a \parbox inside the caption.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `threeparttable` environment, it computes the width of your table, and it works either with the `plain` or the `hang` formats:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\captionsetup{format =plain}%
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
A & B
\\ \midrule
11111111111111111 & 1111111111111111\\
22222222222222222 & 2222222222222222\\
33333333333333333 & 3333333333333333\\
44444444444444444 & 4444444444444444\\
55555555555555555 & 5555555555555555\\
66666666666666666 & 6666666666666666\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption caption caption caption\\
caption caption. }
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
\captionsetup{format =hang}%
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
A & B
\\ \midrule
11111111111111111 & 1111111111111111\\
22222222222222222 & 2222222222222222\\
33333333333333333 & 3333333333333333\\
44444444444444444 & 4444444444444444\\
55555555555555555 & 5555555555555555\\
66666666666666666 & 6666666666666666\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption caption caption caption\\
caption caption. }
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}\end{document}
```

Note that it doesn't seem to work with the `ThreePartTable`environment (from `threeparttablex`), so that you can't break your tables through pages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hang is the standard caption format in KOMA-Script classes. Therefore you only have to measure the width of the float und to set `\setcapwidth` to the result. The `caption` package is not needed.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength\floatwidth
\newcommand\MyFloat[1]{%
  \settowidth\floatwidth{#1}%
  \setcapwidth[c]{\floatwidth}%
  #1%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \MyFloat{%
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \toprule
      A & B\\
      \midrule
      11111111111111111  & 1111111111111111\\
      22222222222222222  & 2222222222222222\\
      33333333333333333  & 3333333333333333\\
      44444444444444444  & 4444444444444444\\
      55555555555555555  & 5555555555555555\\
      66666666666666666  & 6666666666666666\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  }
  \caption{Caption caption caption caption caption caption.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: If there should be a manual line break inside the caption you have to use

```
  \caption{Caption caption caption caption \protect\\ caption caption.}
```

or maybe better

```
  \caption[Caption caption caption caption caption caption.]{%
           Caption caption caption caption \\ caption caption.}
```